# Axios promise is undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, promise, axios

I am having trouble with IE11 and promises using axios. I am using webpack to build the files.

I know promises don't exist in IE11 so you have to polyfill them. From what I've been reading I have seen I have to use - https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

in my webpack file I do:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
```

Then:

`entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', ./${conf.path.src('index')}],
    vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
  }`

However I still get that error. What am I doing wrong?

The app file gets rendered after vendor in my index.html.

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: The exact error is promise is undefined

Comment: `promise is undefined` - probably because it's `Promise` not `promise`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this by adding `import 'babel-polyfill';` above every import of axios.

So my code looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
```